# Why does validation on a subclassed form break?

Tags: django, validation, subclassing, django-forms

When i create CustomerForm() which is a subclass of EnhancedModelForm(), the changes (required=True) made when initializing the form with `__init__()` aren't taken in consideration by the default clean methods? Why is this?

```
class EnhancedModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EnhancedModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        test = self.errors
```

And the form

```
class CustomerForm(EnhancedModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('salutation', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'email_address')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['phone_number'].required = True
        self.fields['email_address'].required = True
```

Comment: This should work. Can you show some code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: You're right, i did some more testing and when i try to access self.errors validation for those modified fields fails (see example above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of overriding the **init**() method, i now use the _post_clean() hook in django.forms.form.BaseForm()

```
"""
An internal hook for performing additional cleaning after form cleaning
is complete. Used for model validation in model forms.
"""
```

This works great